# sort ArrayList<String> using strin length

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I tried searching for this  in here and got answers, but, i think people here are forgetting the point that some ask because they have no idea how to do it. developers here just give a piece of code and say, that should do it.
I mean, we wont stop asking if you don't teach us.

back to the point, I'm looking for a way of sorting an `array list` using its length.

I tried for loops, didn't work

```
for (/* whatever fits here */) {
...
}
```

/*** so I asked ***/

Comment: "we wont stop asking if you dont teach us." . Wrong. You wont stop asking until you learn it by yourself. Now, have a look at Comparator interface.

Comment: Use bubble sort or selection sort algorithm.

Comment: Also note that the accepted answer in the duplicate is pretty well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String  o1, String  o2)
        {    
            return  o1.length()-o2.length();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Quotation from the original question: 'developers here just give a piece of code and say, that should do it. i mean, we wont stop asking if you dont teach us.'

Comment: @aga - Well in that case he must google it.. There are lots of blogs out there which specify how to use the comparator interface...:)

Comment: with supreme googling, i still dont know what to do. but with this, i sort'a understand it now, just do this returns a list that i should set to my list or is it as is?

Comment: @user3213875 You cant assign to list back. The Collections.sort() method will return void. You pass list as argument to sort method. more here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29